# PE44820 Phase Shifter Confusion in Results

Tags: rf, signal-processing, digital-communications, phase-shift

I am using a PE44820 phase shifter for my capstone project. We created our own evaluation board so that we can test it with a raspberry pi3. We are running a simple test first where we are just trying to get the phase shifter to shift only the steps that it comes with (i.e. 1.4, 2.8, 5.6, etc). The only successful ones we have gotten is 45 measured to be 45.8, 90 measured 85.3, and 180 measured 187.7. All the other steps came out to be between 0.07 and 0.18 degrees.

We are sending the data in serial, with the 13 bit binary codes.

To simply put our python script is:

```
import time
import spidev
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# This section is to configure a pin as HIGH
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT) #This is pin 22 on the RPI
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT) #This is pin 18 on the RPI


#This code is for S/PBAR to stay logic HIGH
GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)

bus = 0
device = 1
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(bus, device)

#Setting the SPI speed and mode
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000
spi.mode = 0

#Init to 0 degrees
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
msg = [0x00]
spi.xfer2(msg)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)               

msg = [0b1111111100000]
spi.xfer2(msg)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
```

Where we are changing the binary value to the desired degrees we want. Additionally, if we try a combination, say 180 + 22.5, we get the same measured value as when we just do 180. Same if we do 45 + 1.4, we get the measured value for 45. When we did 45 + 90, we got the value for 45.

Anyone know what might be going on? We understand its not typical SPI, but we can't deduce a commonality outside of that 45, 90, and 180 are the only degrees really working.

**Note, we do have 2 phase shifters on eval boards and they behave exactly the same**

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python.  But are you sure you have the address and phase fields correct in the message?  And the bit order correct in the phase and address fields?  Because it sounds like the DPS is only responding to some messages - where the address field is correct.

Comment: The address remains the same for all messages. So if it is responding to some messages, but not others when the address is kept the same... Wouldn't that indicate that we at least have the right address? We also have verified multiple times that our 13bit's are correct for the degrees we want to phase shift. Thankfully this phase shifter comes with a lot of documentation as to how the bits need to be sent to the shifter. Which is why we are struggling so much with this... We've made sure to do things based off the Data Sheet, yet we can only get 3 options to work consistently.

Comment: It might help is you could add a snippet of the Python code for some of he other phase states you're trying to command.

Comment: we manually rewrite the binary message. So for 45, the binary is 0b0000010000000. For 90 the binary is 0b0000001000000.

How the data sheet has the message it is [phase 2bytes][OPT 1bit][address 1byte] and the binary for the state is sent backwards. So 45 degrees is state 32, which the binary for 32 is 00100000, but in the message we have to send 00000100 then add the opt bit, which we have as 0, then we are addressing only one client so its address is 0000.

Comment: I'm going to have to think about your comment.  I have downloaded the data sheet.